# How can I get email id of owner for OCI's Tenant ? via SDK?

Tags: java, oracle

I want to retrieve the email id of the tenancy's owner from the SDK. So far I have only found one way to do so it this. https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/identity-cloud/17.4.6/rest-api/op-admin-v1-Tenants-%7Bid%7D-get.html